# how to specify all ports in client access policy file - silverlight

Tags: silverlight, cross-domain, clientaccesspolicy.xml

How do I specify a wildcard '*' for the ports in a client access policy file?

If I want to specify multiple ports in the following file is there anyway to do this using a wildcard instead of explicitly listing each server:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from http-request-headers="*">
      <domain uri="http://*.foobar.net:81" />
      <domain uri="http://*.foobar.net:82" />
      <domain uri="http://*.foobar.net:83" />
      <domain uri="http://*.foobar.net:84" />
    </allow-from>
  <grant-to>
    <resource path="/*" include-subpaths="true"/>
  </grant-to>
</policy>
```

Ideally I want to be able to do something like:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <access-policy>
      <cross-domain-access>
        <policy>
          <allow-from http-request-headers="*">
          <domain uri="http://*.foobar.net:*" />
        </allow-from>
      <grant-to>
        <resource path="/*" include-subpaths="true"/>
      </grant-to>
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

I suspect if this is not allowed and it is because an address containing a port number is viewed as being another domain and therefore requires a cross domain policy file as well as client access policy file, can anyone confirm or deny this as well?

Comment: the only thing I can find so far is this and it doesn't look good - http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/48275/128264.aspx