# silverlight: clientaccesspolicy.xml any localhost?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have an (otherwise) functional clientaccesspolicy.xml file that is not working correctly for requests from localhost unless a specific port is given. Below is my file installed on my **development** server that functions properly for any requests except those coming from any localhost. **It works correctly for locahost requests on port 11712**, but won't accept any others. **This is what I would expect... no problem so far...**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from http-request-headers="SOAPAction">
        <domain uri="http://*.myDomain.us"/>
        <domain uri="http://localhost:11712/"/>
      </allow-from>
      <grant-to>
        <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
      </grant-to>
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

I want to completely open up access to any localhost regardless of port. so if I change the `domain` node thusly:

```
<domain uri="http://localhost:*" />
```

or

```
<domain uri="http://localhost*" />
```

or

```
<domain uri="http://localhost"/>
```

do not work, failing as a cross-site error. The only way localhost access works is if I specify the exact port, which means that I'd have to specify any potential client app in the list (or require them to use a specific port).

Comment: See if this helps at all:

[Self-Hosting clientaccesspolicy.xml][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953932/silverlight-wcf-self-hosting-seemed-not-to-locate-clientaccesspolicy-xml

Comment: It's not possible to do this. There's another open question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026171/how-to-specify-all-ports-in-client-access-policy-file-silverlight

Answer (score 0):

alfonso pointed me in the correct direction. According to Microsoft, the clientAccessPolicy.xml file does NOT allow wildcards in the port:

> Silverlight does not support wildcards for the port field in
>   clientaccesspolicy.xml, and neither does it support the to-ports
>   attribute in the crossdomain.xml. Can you give us a little more
>   information so we can think about adding support for this in the
>   future please - why do you need to be able to launch your XAP from
>   multiple different ports?

from: http://forums.silverlight.net/p/48275/128264.aspx